# GLFW throws "X11: Vulkan instance missing VK_KHR_xcb_surface extension" even when it is in ppEnabledExtensionNames

Tags: c++, x11, vulkan, wayland

I'm following [this tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/), and now I'm trying to create a window surface. Here's my `createSurface()`:

```cpp
void createSurface() {
    int result = glfwCreateWindowSurface(instance, window, nullptr, &surface);
    if(result != VK_SUCCESS) {
        const char* description;
        int code = glfwGetError(&description);
        cout << description << endl;
        throw runtime_error("Window surface creation failed");
    }
}
```

When I run the program, I get this in the end:

```
X11: Vulkan instance missing VK_KHR_xcb_surface extension
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Window surface creation failed
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Seems like my instance is just missing the `VK_KHR_xcb_surface` extension, or is it?

Here's the final part of my `createInstance()`. This part deals with instance extensions and creates the instance in the end:

```cpp
    // Extensions required by GLFW
    uint32_t glfwExtensionsCount = 0;
    const char** glfwExtensions;
    glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionsCount);
    instanceCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = glfwExtensionsCount;
    instanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = glfwExtensions;
    // List enabled extensions in stdout
    cout << "Enabled extensions" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < instanceCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount; i++) {
        cout << instanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames[i] << endl;
    }

    // Create instance
    if(vkCreateInstance(&instanceCreateInfo, nullptr, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        runtime_error("Vulkan instance creation failed");
    }
```

This is what it prints out:

```
Enabled extensions
VK_KHR_surface
VK_KHR_xcb_surface
```

So `VK_KHR_xcb_surface` should be enabled, yet GLFW says otherwise at surface creation. What is wrong here?

I also tried with Wayland, but it only changes `VK_KHR_xcb_surface` into `VK_KHR_wayland_surface`.

**EDIT:** [This](https://pastebin.com/nSBz9mE6) is the output of `vulkaninfo`.

Comment: What does `vulkaninfo` print out?

Comment: @krOoze added it.

Comment: Uninstall 32-bit drivers.

Comment: Is the instance created when you call the `glfwCreateWindowSurface`. Also try `vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkCreateXcbSurfaceKHR")`. If it returns `nullptr`, then something's wrong with your driver. Whats your driver (version) and where you got it from?

Comment: @krOoze implementing the debug messenger from that tutorial fixed it somehow. I have no idea how or why.